# multiplying 2D arrays in C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am quite new to C# and I need some help with multiplying two numbers from a 2d array. I have this code:

> int[,] myArray = { {50,74}, {9,88}, {75,53}, {46,98}, {100,99} };

I need to multiply each pair e.g. 50 * 0.4 and 74 * 0.6, then the two answers from each added together to get my total and the same with the others. Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the following:

```
double[] result = new double[myArray.GetLength(0)];
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); ++i)
    result[i] = myArray[i, 0] * 0.4 + myArray[i, 1] * 0.6;
// result now contains what you need
```

The first index of multidimensional "2D" arrays refers to row position (each constituent array) and the second index refers to the column position (position in each constituent array).

`GetLength(0)` means getting the 0th dimension length of your multidimensional array. In this case, it is 5 because there are five rows in your array. On the other hand `GetLength(1)` will return 2 because there are 2 columns.

Comment: You're doing an integer multiplication here, the numbers will be truncated. Length will also be 10, which will create an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault oops sorry about that. fixed!

Answer (score 1):

First, to go through all pairs, we will need to know how long your array is. To achieve that, we can use `myArray.GetLength(0)`. This will return the total number of elements in the first dimension. Using only `Length` would return the *total* number of elements, which is not what we want.

Once we have that, we can loop through all pairs with a classic `for` loop.

For each pair, we can multiply the first element, `myArray[i,0]` by `0.4d` and the other one, `myArray[i,1]`, by `0.6d`. The `d` here indicate the `double` data type. `int` won't do it here, because we have a number with decimals.

We simply add up the result of those two operations and add it as a new entry in our final list.

Here's the code:

```
int[,] myArray = { { 50, 74 }, { 9, 88 }, { 75, 53 }, { 46, 98 }, { 100, 99 } };

var result = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    result.Add(myArray[i,0] * 0.4d + myArray[i,1] * 0.6d);
}
```

If your final list explicitly needs to be an array, you can use this instead:

```
int arrayLength = myArray.GetLength(0);
double[] result = new double[arrayLength];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    result[i] = myArray[i, 0] * 0.4d + myArray[i, 1] * 0.6d;
}
```

It's pretty much the same thing, but we first need to define an array with the size of our collection.

Comment: `List<double>` will probably fail the assignment, array should be enough.